# Powershell change extension

Tags: powershell, replace, split

I have a problem with change extension of a file. I need to write a script which is replicating data, but data have two files. Filename is not a string, so we can't use normal -replace

I need to get from

```
filename.number.extension
```

this form

```
filename.number.otherextension
```

We try to use a split, but this command show us things like below

```
filename
number
otherextension
```

Thanks for any ideas,

Answer (score 12):

```
[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension("test.old",".new")
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like the `-replace` operator:

```
'filename.number.extension' -replace 'extension$','otherextension'
```

- The `$` is regular expression syntax meaning *end of line*. This should ensure that the `-replace` does not match "extension" appearing elsewhere in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\text files\more text\*' *.txt | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "doc") }
```

Answer (score 1):

**A simple Utility Function**

```
<#
 # Renames all files under the given path (recursively) whose extension matches $OldExtension.
 # Changes the extension to $NewExtension
 #>
function ChangeFileExtensions([string] $Path, [string] $OldExtension, [string] $NewExtension) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter "*.$OldExtension" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $Destination = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $_.Name.Replace($OldExtension, $NewExtension)
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination -Force
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
ChangeFileExtensions -Path "c:\myfolder\mysubfolder" -OldExtension "extension" -NewExtension "otherextension"
```

But it can do more than just this. If you had the following files in the same folder as your script

```
    example.sample.csv
    example.txt
    mysubfolder/
        myfile.sample.csv
        myfile.txt
```

this script would rename all the .sample.csv files to .txt files in the given folder and all subfolders and overwrite any existing files with those names.

```
# Replaces all .sample.csv files with .txt extensions in c:\myfolder and in c:\myfolder\mysubfolder
ChangeFileExtensions -Path "c:\myfolder" -OldExtension "sample.csv" -NewExtension "txt"
```

If you don't want it to be recursive (affecting subfolders) just change

```
"*.$OldExtension" -Recurse | ForEach-Object
```

to

```
"*.$OldExtension" | ForEach-Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last item with the the [0..-1] slice and add the new extension to that

```
(("filename.number.extension" -split "\.")[0..-1] -join '.') +".otherextension"
```